# Not able turn on the wifi on Lenovo Y520

Tags: wireless, lenovo, 17.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu on a Lenovo Y520. I'm not able to turn on the wifi.

I heard that there are some issues with WiFi in Ubuntu 17.04 but they all are related to connectivity.

I wonder if it could be related to BIOS settings as I had to change a few to install Ubuntu on this machine.

I didn't find any key on the keyboard or any button on the laptop to enable/disable wifi physically.

Wifi is working fine in Windows OS on the same machine. So I don't think it is switched off.

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

There is no change after `rfkill unblock all`

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` Also, isn't Fn+F7 the combination to turn on airplane mode which turns off the wireless radio?

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I had already turned airplane mode off. I have also copied intel driver to "/lib/firmware". But it didn't work. I'll update the question with rfkill cmd op.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

and reboot.

Answer (score -3):

First try `rfkill unblock all`. if this doesn't fix your problem try the following. 
open the file `/etc/network/interfaces` as `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and append the following lines to `/etc/network/interfaces`.

`auto "your wireless interface's name"
iface "your wireless interfaces's name" inet auto`

here replace `"your wireless interface's name"` by the name of your wireless network interface as you see it in `ifconfig -a`". After doing this you have to make the service `network-manager` manages the interfaces listed in `/etc/network/interfaces`, because `network-manager` doesn't manage the interfaces listed in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file out of the box i.e. by default.

To turn on interface management, open the `network-manager` config file i.e. `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. and change the line

`[ifupdown]
managed=false`

to

`[ifupdown]
managed=true` 

then restart the network-manager service by:

`sudo service network-manager restart`

the interface should be managed and up.

If this fails try `ifup "your wireless interface's name"`.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to change `/etc/network/interfaces` . It will disable Network manager. The problem is with `rfkill` and `ideapad_laptop`.

Comment: @endrias it dint work.

Comment: @AmitGupta what does the command `rfkill list` reply?

Comment: @endrias added in question. It was saying hard block :yes and soft block: no