# intel wireless ac 9560 - HARD BLOCKED - failed to load firmware chunk

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi, ubuntu-drivers

Just bought my new computer and already got big problems. This isn't a promising start.

After installing Ubuntu, I have problems with the Intel Wireless AC 9560 adapter. Made some research

```
> rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes

> dmesg | grep -e wl -e iwl
[...] islwifi ... enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[...] islwifi ... loaded firmware version 43.95eb4e97.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[...] islwifi ... Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x354
[...] islwifi ... Failed to load firmware chunk!
[...] islwifi ... ...
[...] islwifi ... ...
[...] islwifi ... Could not load the [0] uCode section
[...] islwifi ... Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[...] islwifi ... ...
```

I downloaded the firmware iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-33.ucode and put in the /lib/firmware and rebooted but nothing.

Have you got any idea on how to fix it?
I don't have an ethernet at disposal, so I am offline and can download things from other computers and move it through a usb drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able turn on the wifi on Lenovo Y520](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929739/not-able-turn-on-the-wifi-on-lenovo-y520)

Comment: Just tried, but nothing changed

Comment: Is it still hard blocked? What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: 18.10. The computer is a lenovo yoga c640. I guess it is still hard blocked. That's weird, cuase now the "rfkill list all" does show only the Bluetooth (and that is not hardblocked anymore, so at least we solved another problem :D)

Comment: 18.10 is EoL and not supported. Install a supported release and all should work.

Comment: Wow. Really? Can I use the 19.10? I've seen it's beta, right? Otherwise I'll go back to 18.04

Comment: Ah, no. I made a mistake. I have a 18.04 already!

Comment: Is there any update on this? I tried the same thing and it didn't work for me too. My laptop is Dell Inspiron with the same wireless hardware and I'm using latest Elementary OS. Kernel version 5.xx

Comment: For me, installing 19.10 has solved the issue

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried newer kernel, like 5.2?

See https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203891